# Augmented reality phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, augmented-reality

I would like to know if I can use phonegap to create a simple augmented reality application.
Can I create an augmented reality browser with phonegap to show pois at camera of Android phone?
Anyone know some references or simple examples?

Comment: what you really want to achieve

Comment: a simple application for my android phone as ARviewer/Layar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap is not just a native wrapper of a web app. Through the PhoneGap javascript APIs, the "web app" has access to the mobile phone functions such as Geolocation, Accelerometer Camera, Contacts, Database, File system, etc. Basically any function that the mobile phone SDK provides can be "bridged" to the javascript world. On the other hand, a normal web app that runs on the mobile web browser does not have access to most of these functions (security being the primary reason). Therefore, a PhoneGap app is more of a mobile app than a web app. You can certainly use PhoneGap to wrap a web app that does not use any PhoneGap APIs at all, but that is not what PhoneGap was created for.
if there is something u want to use in your app that phonegap does not provides then you can create a native plugin and use the functionality in your app. 
thus phonegap can be used to create apps that can match 100% with the functionality provided by a native app. you can give it a try to create your app.

Comment: Thank for answer. As i understand, i can use PhoneGap for Augmented Reality apps and if something does not provide (e.x. browser) i can use android.hardware for solve.Right? I believe that i can use phonegap, (see ARviewer which create with phonegap).

Comment: nt browser, your app will run on webview and yes if somethin phonegap doesnt provide then u can create a native plugin for the purpose. On github you can find many plugins

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Wikitude AR Phonegap Plugin, you can do almost everything with that using JS, HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: it is awesome, and it should have been chosen as Answer

Comment: It's pretty expensive if you're just doing it for fun or not sure how popular your app is going to be.